# How can I get all annotations within a class using ICompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a class `Book` which has some annotations like `@Override`,`@Before`,`@After`.

How can I get those annotations using `ICompilationUnit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javadoc for IAnnotation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IAnnotation.html) states that:

"Annotations are obtained using IAnnotatable.getAnnotation(String).

Note that annotations are not children of their declaring element. To get a list of the annotations use IAnnotatable.getAnnotations()."

What's an IAnnotatable? IField, ILocalVariable, IMethod, IPackageDeclaration, IType.

There are methods on ICompilationUnit for getting objects of those types.